# How to enable keyboard backlight for Ubuntu 18.04 OS on Lenovo Thinkpad L480 laptop

Tags: command-line, 18.04, lenovo, thinkpad, keyboard-backlight

I have tried this option

```
sudo gedit /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.UPower.conf
```

and change setting

```
<allow  send_destination="org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight"
           send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties"/>
```

i have changed tag `<allow>` to `<deny>` but it didn't work.

Second option i have tried below command on terminal

```
 xset led 3
```

This command not work for me.
Please help me out from this unnecessary bug.

Comment: Try `echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/lenovo::kbd_backlight/brightness`

Answer (score 7):

At least with Thinkpad T480 model 
the keyboard led seems to be found under `tpacpi::kbd_backlight`:

So like proposed in comment section,

`echo 2|sudo tee /sys/class/leds/tpacpi::kbd_backlight/brightness`